# Is there a way to include a Next.js application in a WordPress page

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js

I am developing a couple of WordPress plugins with a JavaScipt frontend UI. I chose React as a solution, which could be easily built and included on a WordPress page via shortcodes and wp_enqueue_scripts. Then I came across Nextjs, and I know it can be used to replace WordPress all together (headless), but I need to know if a Nextjs application can be built and included on a single WordPress page.

I have searched Google and Github for examples of Next in WordPress plugins, but I guess since no one uses Nextjs this way, this resulted in zero results.